# Modifying server information for short tag parsing

Tags: php

I am getting parsing error in following code. Can I write this code in some more comprised form or in better way?

```
        <?php if( (!isset($_SESSION["userkey"])) ||  (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) || (!isset($_SESSION["userauthorisation"]))  )
        { ?>
            <div id="loginbox" >
                <form id="loginform" name="loginform" style="margin:0px; background:#000;">
                    XYZ FORM
                </form>
            </div>
        <? } ?>
```

IF I use `<?php ?>` though problem is solved. But can I modify my server information such it won't give me error on short tag i.e `<? ?>`. I am usign XAMPP server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what error do you get?

maybe you should use the full php tag in the last line:

```
    <?php if( (!isset($_SESSION["userkey"])) ||  (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) || (!isset($_SESSION["userauthorisation"]))  )
    { ?>
        <div id="loginbox" >
            <form id="loginform" name="loginform" style="margin:0px; background:#000;">
                XYZ FORM
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yes I was getting parsing error in last line. Might be I was not using php full tag... How can I modify my phpinfo information so that it not give me error for <? ?>? I am modifying my question

Comment: +1 for probably the right answer. Also note that the whole if statement could be more neatly written as `if (!isset($_SESSION["userkey"], $_SESSION["username"], $_SESSION["userauthorisation"])) {` and still mean the same thing.

Comment: @RahulSingh The option you are looking for is [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php). You must modify this in php.ini - it **cannot** be controlled at run-time with `ini_set()`. However, you would do much better to just use the full `<?php` tag.

Comment: @RahulSingh don't use the short tags... your code will not be portable if you do (eg. if you upload the code to a vhost environment where you do not have access to php configuration)

Comment: @Daverandom & @giorgio : I got the point I shouldn't use short tag for php as its not a good practice. BUt can U know please let me know how can I modify my `php.ini` file for now.

Answer (score 3):

There are no syntax error, but you just probably have to switch from `<?` to `<?php`

Answer (score 3):

on what line do you get the parse error?

just a note; the paranthesis around the isset() functions aren't necessary; this will do;

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['userkey']) || !isset(...) )
{
....
}
```

furthermore, if you write your phg code in a html 'environment' (eg. in a view), common practice is to use the alternative syntax;

```
<?php if( !isset($_SESSION['userkey']) || ... ): ?>
    your html
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: great new syntax for me will surely use it. How can I write it for ifelse chain statement?

Comment: do reply for my both question?

Comment: basically the same: `<?php if( expr ): ?> html <?php elseif (expr): ?> morehtml <?php else: ?> last part of html <?php endif; ?>` same with loops: `<?php foreach( expr): ?> looping this, <tr> ie. <?php endforeach; ?>`

Answer (score 3):

To answer the newly updated question, what you need to do is change the php.ini directive [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) to `1`.

Just open your php.ini file, search it for `short_open_tag` (which will be currently set to `0`) and change the value of it to `1`.

However, you would be much better to just use the full `<?php` tag as it will make your code more portable. Is there some reason why you can't do this?

Answer (score 2):

there are too much ')'-brackets - i guess a copy-paste-mistake by you

the line should be

```
if( !isset($_SESSION["userkey"]) ||  !isset($_SESSION["username"]) || !isset($_SESSION["userauthorisation"])  )
```